# Where is the Nest API to deauth an account

Tags: nest

Looking through the Nest Authorizations APIs, I cannot find the API for 'deauth'. Nest documentation indicates that this should be used when user wants to remove nest access.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation to the Deauthorization API.

https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/deauthorization-overview